# Resizable Android Widget

Tags: android, widget, resize

i just tried to program a resizable Widget.

I tried it on my Nexus with Jelly Bean, but i can only resize it horizontaly.

```
<appwidget-provider 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minHeight="100dp"
android:minWidth="280dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal" />
```

I also tried minResizeHeight, but it didnt worked.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: minResizeHeight and minResizeWidth were introduced only to limit resizing to a minimum size. Have you tried using both, or only minResizeHeight?

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"` instead.